# Short-term study visa refused

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

A friend of mine has applied for a 12 week English course in London. She is from Indonesia and this is the first time she will be coming to the UK.

She has provided bank statements showing approximately £5500 of savings in her bank account along with her payslips. We have calculated that her trip(4 months in total as she would be staying for a few extra weeks after the course to take an IELTS test) would cost her around £2500 in total(this does not include the course costs as that is already paid).

Her visa has been refused due to not having enough funds and as she will be quitting her job there is no guarantee she will be able to support herself when she goes back to Indonesia without any money.

I am renting a flat in the UK with my mother and we have provided her a very simple letter of invitation stating our address and that she will be allowed to stay with us for free during her visit. We have not provided any other proof such as our passports, or the tenancy agreement. After the visa has been refused my friend has found a lot of information online that providing proof that we are genuine people(our passports) and proof of accommodation such as the tenancy agreement is very important.

Is it possible that her visa has been refused due to them not believing the accommodation I can provide and assuming that she will have to be renting somewhere? As it's very hard to believe that a trip costing at most £2500-3000 is too expensive while having £5500 in savings available.

Comment: Posting the refusal, with personal information blacked out, would resolve the nature of the refusal. However, given the information in the question it is just as likely to be a concern that she will overstay, for lack of strong ties to her home country.

Comment: It is very common for people to misinterpret visa refusal letters, especially if they are not yet fluent in English. Please post an image of the actual refusal letter (with personal information removed) so that we can give the best possible advice.